# Django - best way to debug LiveServerTestCase testing (error on POST)

Tags: django, debugging, selenium

I am updating all my selenium tests from django-nose to use Django 1.4's LiveServerTestCase. Problem is, I've set up a test case in exactly the way they want, but only GET is working (cannot POST to my website). This is not a selenium problem either because it doesn't work from my chrome browser either. I'm looking for debugging ideas and other help to get me started finding the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be linked to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660956/is-there-any-way-to-start-with-a-post-request-using-selenium)