# How to submit form data with chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

With the following code, I am able to open a web page and retrieve its contents.

Based on this web page contents, I would like to execute a `post` on this page where I supply some `form data`.

How can this be done with the selenium / chromedriver api?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/usr/local/share/chromedriver")

url = r'https:\\somewebpage.com'
result = browser.get(url)
```

Comment: You don't appear to even *attempt* to fill in any data. What have you done so far?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with selenium alone.

What you could do is fill the form / click on the submit button with something like this:

```
input_a = driver.find_element_by_id("input_a")
input_b = driver.find_element_by_id("input_b")

input_a.send_keys("some data")
input_b.send_keys("some data")

driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

If you really want to create the POST request yourself, you should look into the https://github.com/cryzed/Selenium-Requests package, which will allow you to create POST requests just like the Requests package but with Selenium.