# How to Get URL with Parameters using selenium like requests python

Tags: python, selenium

i just tried to do URL requests with selenium like this

```
driver.get (example.com/)
```

but i confused how to do same requests with parameter, like i do with requests

```
params = {
  'name':'john-doe',
  'shop_id':'121323233443',
}

requests.get('example.com/', params=params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request is a backend interaction library and selenium is an front end autoamtion library , you cannot explicitly send plain http calls using selenium. WOrk around is to use javascript executor in selenium to do http ajax calls using javascript inside browser. This not recommended as this just aover engineering design unless its sepcific required use case:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5665291/6793637

Comment: what alternative should used for this case?

Comment: @FeriLukmansyah use request library it self

Comment: @FeriLukmansyah what are you trying to do

Comment: requests url with parameter using selenium

Comment: What should I do if I can't use requests because I need javascript to run, but I still need to get a URL with a query string?