# Is there any way to send authornicated Post and Get API requests with Selenium?

Tags: api, selenium, automation, postman

I can share the real time scenario.

Step 1: Lunch the browser perform some functional test like navigate to some page and upload a image/video file

step 2: Send a authenticated post request.

```
{

  "predicateParams": {

    "type":"dam:Asset",

    "p.offset": "0",

    "p.limit": "-1"

  },"dateParams": {

  "group.1_daterange.lowerBound":"2021-11-19T00:10:15",

  "group.1_daterange.upperBound":"2021-11-19T23:59:15"

  } 

}
```

Steps 3: Read the response and find the preview URL from the response.

```
{
    "totalAssetsModifiedOrCreated": 1,
    "totalAssetsDeleted": 0,
    "deletedAssets": [],
    "hits": [
        {
            "path": "/content/dam/global-asset-library/Products/automation/download.jpg",
            "renditions": [
                "/content/dam/global-asset-library/Products/automation/download.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.web.1280.1280.jpeg"
            ],
            "metadata": {
               //Asset metadata
            },
            "previewLink": "https://qa.dam.com/content/dam/global-asset-library/Products/automation/download.jpg?qtm=1637340248265"
        }
    ],
    "status": {
        "code": "200",
        "message": "Search results found.",
        "success": true
    }
}
```

Step 4: Send a get request using to the preview link in the above response.

```
{

  "predicateParams": {

    "type":"dam:Asset",

    "p.offset": "0",

    "p.limit": "-1"

  },"dateParams": {

  "group.1_daterange.lowerBound":"2021-11-17T00:10:15",

  "group.1_daterange.upperBound":"2021-11-18T23:50:15"

  } 

}
```

Step 5: validate the previously published asset returned(ex: Image)
[Response of get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Vn4.png)

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: If you are looking for someone who will make a job for you it's OK, but not here and it will not be free of charge.

Comment: As you commented on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016384/is-there-any-way-to-send-a-api-get-request-after-performing-some-functional-step/70016667?noredirect=1#comment123853254_70016667 it is a continuation ask for that. Please let us know at what step you are failing and what error message you are getting and what you have tried?

Comment: @Nandan A How to send authorization(username and password) while sending Post request. I tried with RestAssured.basic("dell-sprinklr", "DellSprinklr321%$#@#");
 RestAssured.baseURI = url; but am getting 401 response.

Comment: `401` stands for unauthorized. You are not authorized to access that api.

Comment: Yes, 401 stands for unauthorized. But i am passing valid authorization details only. Using postman am able to access the that api with same details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization(Basic) details can be passed through

```
given().auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password")
```

preemptive() method will send the username and password irrespective of server need authentication or not.